# Python end thread when function it's called from ends and pass up exception from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, scope, python-multithreading

I have the following code where I am running a check periodically in the background for when 5 is hit by a random int generator.

Where I'm getting stuck is trying to:

1. When it hits: Pass up the exception from the thread running random_error when it hits 5 so then it can be caught by the test() function and test() ends.
2. When it doesn't hit: The thread running random_error stops trying and ends when test() ends.

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import random

def random_error():
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        x = random.randint(1,30)
        print(x)
        if x == 5:
            raise ValueError("5 Hit")

def test():
    try:
        countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target = random_error)
        countdown_thread.start()
        y = 0
        while True:
            sleep(1)
            print('still going')
            y += 1
            if y == 10:
                print('didnt hit in time')
                break
    except:
        print("Error caught!")
    
test()
```

Comment: There's no way for a thread to know what function created it or, whether the same function call still is active. Closest solution I can think of would be to create a [_context manager_](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) and use it in a `with` statement in your `test()` function. The context manager would start up the background thread when the `with` statement was entered, and it would ask the thread to shut down and then `join()` the thread upon exit from the `with`. (Sorry I can't spend the time to write up an example right now.)

Answer (score 0):

`random_error` is a completely different thread from `test`.  There is no way to just pass the error.

That said, you still have many options.  `test` can look to see if `countdown_thread.is_alive()`.  You can have `random_thread` do something like set a variable or put a value into a queue before it throws the exception and have `test` check periodically for that.

But there is no way that `test` will get the exception thrown by a different thread.